# Proving that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a locally cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Proving that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a locally cyclic group.

A group $G$ is said to be locally cyclic if any finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.

The following is not a proof, but more me trying to stretch out some general facets of the problem in order to gain insight and then hopefully be able to write a proof. I need some insights!

To prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is locally cyclic, let $\tilde{A}=\{a_1,a_2,...a_k\} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, where $a_i = \frac{r_i}{s_i}$,$(r_i \in \mathbb{Z}, s_i \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$).

Let $<c> = <A> = <a_1,a_2,...a_k>=\{n_1a_1+n_2a_2+.....n_ka_k | n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$,  $\forall i\}$

for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $c \in <a_1,a_2,.....,a_k>$ we have:

$c=n_1a_1+n_2a_2+.....+n_ka_k$ where $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$  $\forall i$.

An arbitrary element of $<a_1,a_2,...,a_k>$ looks like $(r_1)a_1+(r_2)a_2+....+(r_k)a_k$. with $r_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\forall i$

We want to find a $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d(c)=\Sigma_{i=1}^kr_ia_i$ where we are under the working assumption that $c = \Sigma_{i=1}^kn_ia_i$

Let $m_i$ be such that $r_i = n_i - m_i$. Then we have:

$dc = d(\Sigma_{i=1}^kn_ia_i)=\Sigma_{i=1}^kr_ia_i=^k\Sigma_{i=1}^k(n_i-m_i)a_i$

If this equation is solvable for $d$ then $d = \frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^k(n_i-m_i)a_i}{\Sigma_{i=1}^kn_ia_i}$.

I'm trying to understand why this fraction must be an integer

Comment: An easier proof: (1) Every fininitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ is isomorphic to a subgroup .of $\mathbb Z.$ . (2) Every subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic.

Comment: "Let $\langle c\rangle=\dots$ seems wrong. You really seem to be assuming $c\in \dots.$

Comment: Can you give me a hint to this isomorphism?

Comment: You should use \langle and \rangle for angle brackets. Compare $c\in<a,b>$ and $c\in\langle a,b\rangle$.